# Why my local machine doesn't get all the files listed on Github?

Tags: flutter, dart, github

My `/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin` directory:

[image]

**Flutter version:**

```
Flutter 2.3.0-0.1.pre • channel dev
Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-18.0.dev)
```

But when I go to the [Github page](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/dev/sdk/bin) for dev channel, it lists many more files. Why can't I find them on my local machine. I also noticed that my machine has `dartaotruntime` exec but there's no such file on the Github link. I'm using the latest version of dev channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Dart, you are not just getting the the files from the Github repository. The Dart distribution are being compiled and assembled before it is distributed as e.g. a zip file. Some of this assembling is picking files for the target platform (e.g. Windows, Linux, Mac OSX etc.).

So you cannot just look at the source code repository and conclude that these files must also be there in the assembled distribution. This is just not how it works.

For details, you can see the following building script which are determining what files should be part of the assembled distribution when building for a given platform: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dev/sdk/BUILD.gn

Comment: Thanks, but where is `dartaotruntime` on the Github page?

Comment: If you check the files in the linked Github directory, you can see they are all scripts. `dartaotruntime` are a compiled binary which contains the Dart runtime which is needed when you have compiled your program ahead of time (AOT). `dartaotruntime` is also linked together with your program when you are compiling it into a standalone executable.

Comment: Since `dartaotruntime` is a binary executable based on the rest of the Dart repository, it does not make sense to upload it into Github (which is also seen as bad behavior. You should in general on upload compiled binaries to GIT projects).

Comment: See the following part of the `BUILD.gn` script: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dev/sdk/BUILD.gn#L331 . Here we can see the `dartaotruntime` is being copied from some directory, containing compiled files, into the `bin` folder in the released distribution.

Comment: Is there any difference between `script` and `[binary] executable`?

Comment: @iDecode A script is a text file which are being interpreted by e.g. `bash`, `python` etc. A binary executable is a file containing machine code which the CPU can execute directly. On Windows you can say that (in very general terms) that `bat` files are scripts and `exe` are binary executable.

Comment: On Linux, you can often see in scripts that they are starting with e.g. `#!/bin/sh`. This is telling the OS that it should give the script to `/bin/sh` for interpreting it (and therefore run it).

Comment: The reason I asked you the question is because in your first comment you wrote "If you check the files in the linked Github directory, you can see they are all scripts." -- shouldn't it be "binary executables" instead of the word "scripts"?

Comment: @iDecode No? The files in the Github repository are text files, which need a interpreter to be executed (and are therefore scripts), and does not contain binary data. That is my whole point. Your don't, in general, upload binary executable to a GIT repository. Try open the files on your own Github link and see for yourself.

Comment: Ahh now I understood your point, thanks for clearing it up :)